# Adding a subelement to a subelement lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am using lxml in an attempt to to output the following xml code:

```
<annotation>
    <folder>images</folder>
    <filename>IMG_8111.JPG</filename>
    <size>
        <width>400</width>
        <height>400</height>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>Bottle</name>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>16</xmin>
            <ymin>71</ymin>
            <xmax>390</xmax>
            <ymax>323</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

Im using [this](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) tutorial to learn how to implement lxml for my needs. The issue I am facing is that my desired output has subelements to subelements. For instance - `<annotation>` is my main element, and then `<folder>`, `<filename>` and `<size>` are subelements, but then, `<height>` and `<width>' are subelements to the`` subelements. How do I make this happen with lxml. I have the following so far:

```
from lxml import etree
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET


root = etree.Element("annotation")
etree.SubElement(root, "folder").text = "Child 1"
etree.SubElement(root, "filename").text = "Child 2"
size = etree.SubElement(root, "size").text = "Child 3"
etree.SubElement(size, "width").text = "Child 4"


with open ('xmltree.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print = True))
```

But it throws the following error:

```
 etree.SubElement(size, "width").text = "Child 4"
TypeError: Argument '_parent' has incorrect type (expected lxml.etree._Element, got str)
```

Please help me out on what I am doing wrong and how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for `size = etree.SubElement(root, "size").text = "Child 3"` to be evaluated as you expect it to be, it would have to be interpreted as:

```
(size = etree.SubElement(root, "size")).text = "Child 3"
```

In Python, you can't perform an assignment in an expression. Instead, the way Python interprets this is:

```
size = "Child 3"
etree.SubElement(root, "size").text = "Child 3"
```

You could rewrite your code using two separate lines to achieve your desired result:

```
size = etree.SubElement(root, "size")
size.text = "Child 3"
```

After looking through the `lxml` API, it does not appear to be a way way to both create an element and assign a value to the `text` attribute in a single line.

Comment: Thank you! That took care of the error and I also understand why now.  Please look at my response below

Answer (score 1):

Your variable size has type string because it has "child 3" value. You should do:

```
size = etree.SubElement(root,"size")
size.text = "child 3" 
etree.SubElement(size, "width").text="child 4"
```